# Normalize special character font

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm creating bots which need to memorise users' nicknames as a string but some users have a special character in their nickname like   or Ⓑⓛⓐⓒⓚ ⓇⒶⓥⓔⓝ. How can I do to convert it to regular characters without doing a giant dictionary with all the font in the world?

Comment: It is unicode characters and there is no way(without a big dictionary) to convert them. May be there is some library, that is doing this work, but there is no usually need it

Comment: Have you tried `unidecode("  or Ⓑⓛⓐⓒⓚ ⓇⒶⓥⓔⓝ")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stdlib solution

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', '  ')
'Black RAven '
>>>
```

---

I personally would probably do something like

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> normalize = partial(unicodedata.normalize, 'NFKD')
>>> normalize('  ')
'Black RAven '
>>>
```

[NFKD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unidecode`.

```
from unidecode import unidecode
print (unidecode("  or Ⓑⓛⓐⓒⓚ ⓇⒶⓥⓔⓝ"))
```

Output:

```
Black RAven or Black RAven
```